# Meaning of *((volatile UINT32*)(a)) in C

Tags: c, volatile

What is the meaning of

```
 *((volatile UINT32*)(a)) ?
```

in C langauage?

Give me some example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It dereferences `a`, after first casting it to type "pointer to volatile `UINT32`".

There are way more parentheses than needed, it would be better written as:

```
*(volatile UINT32 *) a
```

That does the same thing. You'd expect there to be some more code here, of course, either a write:

```
*(volatile UINT32 *) a = 4711;
```

that writes `4711` to the address contained in `a`, making sure (due to the `volatile`) that the write is not optimized out even if it can seem pointless from the compiler's point of view.

Or a read:

```
const UINT32 packetCounter = *(volatile UINT32 *) a;
```

which reads the current value at the address in `a`, and stores it in a local constant variable called `packetCounter`. This is how it would look if `a` is the address of some I/O register. Again due to the `volatile`, the read must happen, it cannot be optimized out or cached even though it might seem pointless to the compiler. This is common with I/O registers.

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer No, that'd be `UINT32 * volatile`, which is very rare. See [this page](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword) for instance.

Comment: So it is like `const`. I always get confused by the prefix notation and use `string const &` instead, thus being able to 'read the type from right to left'.